# No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' is defined

Tags: spring, jpa

I am writing a Unit Test in SpringBoot JPA but I keep getting this error 
"No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' is defined". It is my understanding that Spring Boot should automatically create the EntityManager from the application.yml file properties and I have defined the datasource properties in application.yml file

```
spring:
  profiles: xxxx
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/minglechat?currentSchema=public
    username: postgres
    password: abc123
  jpa:
   generate-ddl: false
   hibernate.ddl-auto: create-only   
   show-sql: true
```

And here is the error stack trace

```
    *************************** APPLICATION FAILED TO START *************************** Description: Field userRepository in com.infor.mingle.chat.rest.OrderController required a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' that could not be found. Action: Consider
    defining a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' in your configuration. 

2016-12-30 12:35:13.384 ERROR 10308 --- [ main] o.s.test.context.TestContextManager : Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener@13c27452]
    to prepare test instance [test.java.com.infor.mingle.chat.rest.OrderControllerTest@19542407] java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
    ~[spring-test-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE] at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83) ~[spring-test-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE] at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:189)
    ~[spring-test-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE] at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:131) ~[spring-test-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE] at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:230)
    ~[spring-test-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE] at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:228) [spring-test-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE] at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:287)
    [spring-test-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE] at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12] at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    [spring-test-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE] at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:247) [spring-test-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE] at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
    [spring-test-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE] at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12] at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12] at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    [junit-4.12.jar:4.12] at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12] at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12] at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    [spring-test-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE] at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70) [spring-test-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE] at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    [junit-4.12.jar:4.12] at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191) [spring-test-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE] at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    [.cp/:na] at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38) [.cp/:na] at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459) [.cp/:na] at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
    [.cp/:na] at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382) [.cp/:na] at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192) [.cp/:na] Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
    Error creating bean with name 'orderController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userDao': Cannot create inner
    bean '(inner bean)#2c30b71f' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner
    bean)#2c30b71f': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' is defined at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:569)
    ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE] at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE] at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:349)
    ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE] at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1219) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE] at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE] at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE] at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE] at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE] at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE] at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE] at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:751)
    ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE] at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:861) ~[spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE] at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541)
    ~[spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE] at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761) ~[spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE] at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:371)
    ~[spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE] at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE] at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:111)
    ~[spring-boot-test-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE] at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98) ~[spring-test-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE] at
    org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116) ~[spring-test-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE] ... 25 common frames omitted Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
    Error creating bean with name 'userDao': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#2c30b71f' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
    Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#2c30b71f': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory'
    is defined at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:313) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE] at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:129)
    ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE] at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1486) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE] at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1231)
    ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE] at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE] at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE] at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE] at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE] at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE] at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE] at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:207) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE] at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1128)
    ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE] at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1056) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE] at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:566)
    ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE] ... 43 common frames omitted Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#2c30b71f': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory'
    while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' is defined at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359)
    ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE] at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE] at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:634)
    ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE] at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:448) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE] at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1128)
    ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE] at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1023) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE] at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
    ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE] at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE] at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:299)
    ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE] ... 56 common frames omitted Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' is defined at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:677)
    ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE] at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1180) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE] at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:284)
    ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE] at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE] at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351)
    ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE] ... 64 common frames omitted
```

And I have tried to create the EntityManager programatically but still getting the same error

```
package com.infor.mingle.chat.config;

import java.util.Map;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.lookup.AbstractRoutingDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;

import com.infor.mingle.chat.Util.TenantContext;


@Configuration
@PropertySource("file:application.properties")
public class MultitenantDataSource extends AbstractRoutingDataSource{

        private Map<Object, DataSource> resolvedDataSources;
@Bean
        public DataSource dataSource() {
          DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
            dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");
            dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/minglechat?currentSchema=public");
            dataSource.setUsername("postgres");
            dataSource.setPassword("abc123");
            return dataSource;
        }

        @Bean(name={"entityManagerFactory"})
        public EntityManager entityManager() {
            return entityManagerFactory().getObject().createEntityManager();
        }

        @Bean
        public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
            LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
            em.setDataSource(dataSource());
            em.setPackagesToScan("com.infor.mingle.entities");
            return em;
        }




}
```

Here is the Unit Test

```html
package test.java.com.infor.mingle.chat.rest;

import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.get;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.test.context.web.WebAppConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders;
import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext;

import com.infor.mingle.chat.rest.OrderController;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@SpringBootTest(classes = OrderController.class)
public class OrderControllerTest {

 
  @Autowired
  private WebApplicationContext wac;
  
  private MockMvc mockMvc;
 
  @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
   MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(wac).build();
    }
 

    @Test                                                          
    public void testSampleOrder() throws Exception {
        this.mockMvc.perform(get("/api/testSampleOrder"))
                .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }
    
    @Test                                                          
    public void testGetUsers() throws Exception {     
        this.mockMvc.perform(get("/api/getUsers/{tenantName}","tenant1")).andExpect(status().isOk());
    }
}
```

Comment: Your configuration will even make it worse, Your `EntityManager` (which you shouldn't even be creating!) is overriding the `EntityManagerFactory`. So actually that class even makes it worse... Also why on earth would that need to be an `AbstractRoutingDataSource` if it is configuration! If the `EntityManagerFactory` isn't created, either your test is wrong or you haven't included the proper dependencies for auto configuration to work.

Comment: I have tried using simple Configuration without extending anything, but still getting the same error.

Comment: You shouldn't be needing this configuration in the first place. As mentioned if it isn't creating the entity manager factory you probably have an issue in your dependencies. So you should be removing this configuration and start from there. Add your unit test to the question.

Comment: I have added Unit Test to the question